# SQL Server query inner join with date field doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. With dates (table1)

```
date
-----------
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-04
2014-01-05
2014-01-06
2014-01-07
2014-01-08
2014-01-09
2014-01-10
2014-01-11
2014-01-12
2014-01-13
2014-01-14
2014-01-15
2014-01-16
2014-01-17
2014-01-18
2014-01-19
2014-01-20
2014-01-21
2014-01-22
2014-01-23
2014-01-24
2014-01-25
2014-01-26
2014-01-27
2014-01-28
2014-01-29
2014-01-30
2014-01-31
```

and one view (view1) with dates and other columns.

```
date        | CustomerID
-------------------------
2014-01-02  2
2014-01-03  2
2014-01-04  2
2014-01-05  2
2014-01-06  2
2014-01-07  2
2014-01-08  2
2014-01-09  2
2014-01-10  2
2014-01-11  2
2014-01-12  2
2014-01-13  2
2014-01-14  2
2014-01-15  2
2014-01-16  2
2014-01-17  2
2014-01-18  2
2014-01-19  2
2014-01-20  2
2014-01-21  2
2014-01-22  2
2014-01-23  2
2014-01-24  2
2014-01-25  2
2014-01-26  2
2014-01-27  2
2014-01-28  2
2014-01-29  2
2014-01-30  2
2014-01-31  2
```

I want the query to return all the records from table1 and when the date is the same return also the CustomerID. I though that a simple query would be enough but it always returns 30 records not 31 (the first table has 31 days and the second has 30 records, the view1 doesnt have the 2014-01-01).

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN.. then you will get all records from Table 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.DATE, V.CustomerID
FROM TABLE1 T
LEFT JOIN VIEW1 V on T.DATE = V.DATE
```

**Edit:**

```
SELECT T.DATE, V.CustomerID
FROM TABLE1 T
LEFT JOIN VIEW1 V on T.DATE = V.DATE
AND V.CustomerID = 2
--AND V.DATE BETWEEN 'YYYYMMDD' AND 'YYYYMMDD'
```

Comment: I am using the folowing but it still returns 30 records instead of 31 :<br>`code`SELECT T.date, V.CustomerID
FROM TABLE1 T LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      VIEW1 V ON T.Date = V.Date
WHERE     (V.CustomerID= 2)`code`

Comment: I forgot to tell you that the view has dates from 2003 and many customers. So I filter it to narrow my results

Comment: I am afraid I do not really understand now. If you need to also include some date condition, please use the commented part of SQL code in my answer.

Comment: The view contains a number of records of various dates (that includes the dates from my example 2014-02-02 to 2014-02-31 for customer 2. If the user selects period 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-31, I want to show to him and the day that is not in the view (the 2014-01-01). I thought that if I create a table of dates of the whole year I could create a simple query and get something like: 2014-01-01 Null, 2014-01-02 Customer2 etc. This works with table but not with my view

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X.DATE, Y.CustomerID
FROM YourTable X
LEFT JOIN YourView Y on X.DATE = Y.DATE
```